# How to install brakes with clamps that are too tight

Tags: maintenance, mountain-bike, brakes, installation

I recently picked up a set of Avid DB1's and put them on my bike, but it was a bear to get them on. For background, they've got a split clamp that is similar to a seat tube where simple compression keeps it in place versus a two-piece clamp that requires more than one screw to tighten.

What I found was that the clamp, even when loosened all the way, would not slide down the handlebar and I had to shimmy it back and forth to move them further in, which ended up scratching and removing a large amount of paint (it's ok, that part goes under the grips). But this doesn't seem right to me. Is there:

1. a better way to install them?
2. different handlebar diameters that would complicate installation?
3. something else I totally missed?

Comment: All handlebars are not he same diameter.  The lever needs to match the handlebar diameter. But most mountain are the same size.

Comment: Did you follow the [installation instructions](https://sram-cdn-pull-zone-gsdesign.netdna-ssl.com/cdn/farfuture/KN-DO2tGZ9cUVkTjBi4lx_uHSP8OJUe6qcOKqWy0SEw/mtime:1372788148/sites/default/files/techdocs/95-7015-012-000_rev_c_mtb_brakes_shifters.indd_.pdf)?

Comment: @Batman, there weren't any supplied as it was a CL purchase. Also, none of those clamp styles match the brakes. I'll see if I can grab a photo later.

Comment: Those are the instructions Avid provides for the DB1 on their website, so I'm somewhat surprised if the instructions don't match.

Comment: @Batman Perhaps because they were OEM take-offs?

Answer (score 3):

A general procedure with too tight clamps: Put in the screw or a longer one of the same diameter from the opposite side. Fit a piece of (hard, like a small coin) metal into the slot. Tighten the screw carefully. It should open the clamp enough to fit it over the bar